# LocalNotification Not Fire On Region Based

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, uilocalnotification, geofencing

Hi I am trying to make the alarm app but this will work on region based.User select the place and if the user reach at that place the local notification fire.

```
-(void)openLocationSearchControl{

    double userLatitude = [lat doubleValue];
    double userLongtitude = [lon doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLatitude, userLongtitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001);
    GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                         coordinate:southWest];
    GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
    _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];



    [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        if (place != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);

            NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
            NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
            self.notifLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:place.coordinate.latitude longitude:place.coordinate.longitude];

            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.alertBody = place.name;
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 4;
            notification.regionTriggersOnce = NO;
            notification.region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:self.notifLocation.coordinate radius:100 identifier:@"PlaceName"];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

            if (place.formattedAddress == NULL ) {



            }else{


            }


        } else {
            NSLog(@"No place selected");
        }
    }];

}
```

Now i am trying to schedule Local Notification like that but i didn't receive any notification.Let me know what am i doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented code to get permission for local notification from user?

Comment: @vivek yes i have implement this code in app delegate

Comment: ok so if you have implemented code then when you will fire local notification it should work..can you check?

Comment: Yes i check it but local notification not fire when i enter into the region.

Comment: presentLocalNotificationNow what will be outcome if you fire notification using mentioned method? Just check you are getting instant notification or not?

Comment: presentLocalNotificationNow is also not working. I tried it now.

Comment: Simple notification is working but region based notification is not working that's the main problem.

Comment: Apple map working accurately in some country while in some countries it is not working asa per the need. Try to increase range or room around the location. Also as per Apple Guide you have to stay in region minimum 20 Sec.